# Separate date and time from csv column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I have a CSV file which has a column datetime in this format:

| datetime | dataA | dataB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 211201000000 | 1 | 222 |
| 211201000000 | 11 | 221 |
| 211201000000 | 12 | 111 |
| 211201000000 | 11 | 144 |
| 211201000000 | 13 | 1122 |

I want to write datetime column in this format (`format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`):

```
2021-12-01 00:00:00
2021-12-01 00:00:00
2021-12-01 00:00:00
2021-12-01 00:00:00
2021-12-01 00:00:00
```

I am using this line to change my datetime column:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

or

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']).dt.date
```

Output I get in datetime column from above lines are:

```
1970-01-01 }
.........
........
```

which are not even in CSV columns.

But these lines don't change my date time as I expect.

How can I change them in to my desire format so that I can use it easily in further work?

Comment: Unless you are specifically asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have removed them both for the time being.

Comment: *None* of this is in CSV format. Is your input actually `|`-delimited? If not, please [edit] to provide an actual sample of the input file, as text.

Comment: Yes, date time is in mentioned format. It was received from MongoDB. Thanks. And apologies for inappropriate tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you need to use is `%y%m%d%H%M%S`. A short example:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

s = "211201000000"

dt.strptime(s, "%y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 0, 0)
```

If you have already a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"date":["211201000000", "211201000000"]})

df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format = "%y%m%d%H%M%S")

df
```

**OUTPUT**

```
        date
0 2021-12-01
1 2021-12-01
```

Then, you can format your date the way you prefer, for example:

```
df["date"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
0    2021-12-01 00:00:00
1    2021-12-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks, it was useful,  I changed 'format='format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' and it works now.